# Displaying a Vuetify Material Design v-icon, without the tag

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a bunch of HTML text, and in this text I'd like to use a Material design icon. For example:

```
var htmlText = "<p>Hello world, have an icon: <v-icon small>mdi-alert</v-icon>.</p>
```

Which in the template we'll code like so:

```
<div v-html="htmlText"/>
```

As the v-icon is a vuetify tag, it won't be rendered, so the output will be:

```
Hello world, have an icon: mdi-alert.
```

I believe that a possible option might be to use `Vue.compile` (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-compile). However, I don't have just one string but a nested object containing a lot of html strings, so this approach feels a bit cumbersome (and potentially a performance problem?), especially because the only tag I actually need to render is the `v-icon`.

Since I'm already importing the Vuetify lib, which probably imported a MDI lib somewhere, isn't there another way to display a Material Design icon, without going through `v-icon`?

What would be a good solution for this?

Comment: https://dev.materialdesignicons.com/getting-started/webfont

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Vuetify, the solution is to use this format:

```
Bob lives in a <span class="mdi mdi-home"></span>.
```

Thanks to Michal Levý for pointing into the right direction.